# Make [google-script] a synonym of [google-apps-script]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

Now there is no question with [google-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-script) and it was removed from the tags autocomplete.

---

Few moments ago there were 62 questions tagged [google-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-script). Most of the question that I already take a look on them today with this tag looks to be about [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script). The confusion could be originated because on Google Drive the file type is called "Script" and the related URLs use `script` as the short name for Google Apps Script:

- http://script.google.com  and http://www.google.com/script creates a new Google Apps Script project.
- http://www.google.com/script/start points the micro-site about Google Apps Script.

Comment: Please wait for some discussion on your synonym request before you start [editing tag wikis out of context](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13211282).

Comment: I proposed an edit to the tag wiki to get attention this this post. Is there another way to do that?

Comment: I linked to the wrong edit, I meant to link to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13211281) one.  That's not a good edit.

Comment: The first link in the above comments points to the tag excerpt, the second to the tag wiki. It's still not clear for me how is the proper way to proceed in this case. Anyway, thanks for those links.

Comment: Even googling 'google script' turns up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script on the first page of results in preference to google-scripts...

Comment: Given your update - does anything need doing on this? Slightly confused...

Comment: @JonClements: I don't know if there is anything else that could be done. It'll be nice if this tag could blocked someway to avoid that it be used again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK Nothing have to be done.