# Merge googlescript into google-apps-script

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

It seems that the tag **[googlescript]** is being used instead of **[google-apps-script]** for Apps Script questions.

The tag is rarely used anymore, but newer users might be led to believe that it is the correct one.

This is a similar situation to these two other posts:

- [Confusion between [appscript] and [google-apps-script]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390701/confusion-between-appscript-and-google-apps-script)
- [Make [google-script] a synonym of [google-apps-script]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329866/make-google-script-a-synonym-of-google-apps-script)

Should we remove the [googlescript] tag or make it a synonym of [google-apps-script]?

For those unfamiliar with Google Apps Script, it is a JavaScript "flavor" that can be run on G Suite applications (Docs, Sheets, Gmail, etc) and can be used to create web apps, custom functions, automated routines, etc.

There is no "Google Script" *per se*, this is a not-so-common way of referring to "Google Apps Script".

Comment: I would just create a synonym on it.

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Nowadays [googlescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/googlescript) is a synonym of [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script), by the other hand [Make [google-script] a synonym of [google-apps-script]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329866/make-google-script-a-synonym-of-google-apps-script) has [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)